# CryptoJS encryption and java side decryption

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I am trying to encrypt password with cryptojs and then I will decrypt the encrypted string on server side. I added script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/aes.js"></script> 
 var key="abcdef";
 var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, key);
```

I am getting error 
ReferenceError: CryptoJS is not defined

Can someone tell me how can i do encryption in jsp and decrypt it on java side with key defined on jsp.
Thank you.

I found core library and Now I can encrypt and decrypt on Jsp

```
 var encryptedpassword=CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password,'abcd');
          var ciphertext = encryptedpassword.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
          console.log(ciphertext);
```

and decrypted using following

```
  var decryptedpassword=CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedpassword,'abcd');
          var plaintext = decryptedpassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
         console.log(plaintext);
```

My problem now is I want to decrypt the encrypted password on java side can some one tell me how can I do it?

Comment: You seem to be missing the CryptoJS core library

Comment: Is there a reason you just don't use HTTPS? Since you are transmitting the key over the wire anyway...

Comment: can you tell me where can I get core library? I need to figure it out with http only

Comment: How about https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js…?

Comment: Tried this one also. Even downloaded it still same error